# shape with different radius corners cannot apply on ImageView

Tags: android

So, I have this shape which simply adds corners of radius 25dip to top corners and it works well on any kind of view but ImageViews, I also noticed that this behavior happens only on different corners shapes it works fine if shape corners have the same radius.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="0dip"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dip" android:bottomRightRadius="0dip"
        android:topLeftRadius="25dip" android:topRightRadius="25dip"/>
</shape>
```

ImageView code sample

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/product_item_thumbnail_iv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/no_image"
            android:background="@drawable/product_item_image"/>
```

**what I tried:**

- setClipToOutline(true); doesn't work even on API level above 24
- wrap ImageView in a FrameLayout and apply the corners to the layout: ImageView was not clipped

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.product_item_thumbnail_iv);
Bitmap bitImg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
R.drawable.product_item_image);

image.setImageBitmap(getRoundedCornerImage(bitImg));
```

and function:

```
public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerImage(Bitmap bitmap, int radius) {
    int w = bitmap.getWidth();
    int h = bitmap.getHeight();
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(0, 0, w, h);

    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, radius, radius, paint);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, rectF, paint);

    /**
     * here to define your corners, this is for left bottom and right bottom corners
     */
    final Rect clipRect = new Rect(0, radius, w + radius, h + radius);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC));
    canvas.drawRect(clipRect, paint);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, rectF, paint);

    bitmap.recycle();
    return output;
}
```